# website showing 403-forbidden, .htaccess file has changed because of back up

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have back up files from public_html using filezilla, but after doing it my website shows 403-forbidden. In .htaccess file 'order deny,allow' at the top of the page and 'deny from all' at the end. I have tried to rewrite it, but it shows error message.

I do not know what to do. Please help me.
.htacces code

## BEGIN HG BLOCK

order deny,allow
allow from 180.234.84.6 # Authenticated with FTP.
allow from 123.49.20.185 # Authenticated with FTP.
allow from 180.234.228.232 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 113.11.101.107 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 180.234.184.50 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 180.234.255.78 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 180.234.62.229 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 180.234.197.73 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 192.184.0.222 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 180.234.75.201 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 180.234.85.198 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 180.234.44.118 # Authenticated with cPanel.
allow from 175.107.133.185 # GTMetrix
allow from 217.27.250.160 # GTMetrix
allow from 74.86.15.72 # GTMetrix
allow from 204.187.12.90 # GTMetrix
allow from 204.187.14.75 # GTMetrix
allow from 204.187.14.73 # GTMetrix
allow from 180.149.241.242 # GTMetrix
allow from 204.187.14.74 # GTMetrix
allow from 74.202.255.240/29 # HostGator
allow from 216.110.94.224/27 # HostGator
allow from 173.11.193.20/29 # HostGator
allow from 50.97.105.36 # HostGator
allow from 216.110.94.176/28 # HostGator
allow from 199.187.122.67 # ManageWP.com
allow from 199.187.122.66 # ManageWP.com
allow from 78.46.70.238 # ManageWP.com
allow from 123.49.21.116 # Manually Added
allow from 123.49.22.135 # Manually Added
allow from 184.172.176.52 # devrim.websitewelcome.com
deny from all

## END HG BLOCK

Besides .htaccess, i found other files like **.htaccess.montool.some numbers.bak**.

Comment: Paste the contents of your current htaccess in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your IP address to the `allow from` list. Add it like
`allow from w.x.y.z` where `w.x.y.z` should be your external IP address.
 You can find that address via http://whatismyipaddress.com/.

Comment: It works! thank you @Thom Wiggers. But I've not understand why it happened. Why backing up of files using _filezilla_ affects .htaccess file?

Comment: If you restored a backup it might be that you now have a different IP address than you had when you made it. This `.htaccess` file restricts browsing the site to the defined list of IPs.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me me recently, this usually happens and intended by hostgator because at some point you might be exceeding their server limit/quota, cpu usage etc, better to ask hostgator support.